# How to resolve Login Authentication - The Username is Required

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I am using IdentityDBContext in ASP,NET Core Web API Authentication.

LoginRequestDto:

```
public class LoginRequestDto
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Username is required!")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The password is required!")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

UserDto:

```
public class UserDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

AuthMapper:

```
public class AuthMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AuthMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();

}
```

Services:

```
public interface IAuthService
{
    Task<GenericResponseDto<object>> LoginUser(LoginRequestDto request);
}

public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public AuthService(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IMapper mapper,
        MyDbContext context

    )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<GenericResponseDto<object>> LoginUser(LoginRequestDto request)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);
        var response = new GenericResponseDto<object>();

        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
        {
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };
            foreach (var userRole in roles)
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }
            var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

            response.Result = new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                user = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),
                expires = token.ValidTo
            };
            response.StatusCode = 200;
            user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto() { ErrorCode = 500, Message = ex.Message };
            }
            return response;
        }

        response.StatusCode = 400;
        response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto { ErrorCode = 400, Message = "Invalid Username or Password!" };

        return response;
    }
}
```

startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
```

And finally the controller:

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<GenericResponseDto<object>>> Login(LoginRequestDto loginRequest)
    {
        var response = await _authService.LoginUser(loginRequest);
        Response.StatusCode = response.StatusCode ?? StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        return new JsonResult(response);
    }
```

MyDbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRole { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        //this.SeedUsers(builder);
        //this.SeedRoles(builder);
        //this.SeedUserRoles(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
            entity.HasIndex(u => u.UserName).IsUnique();
        });
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(r => r.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasIndex(r => r.Name).IsUnique();
        });
}
```

IdentityModel:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
 {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
 }

 public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long>
 {
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
 }

 public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
 {
    public override long UserId { get; set; }
    public override long RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
 }
}
```

When I tried to test on POSTMAN using:

```
{
  "UserName": "test1",
  "Password": "testing"
}
```

I got this error:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "UserName": [
            "The Username is required!"
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-85425a074a2e28429336677742b609de-3c4e2827a8fcaa40-00"
}
```

User logs in with UserName and not email.

When I even updated the controller, adding FromBody. I got the same error:

```
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<GenericResponseDto<object>>> Login([FromBody] LoginRequestDto loginRequest)
    {
        var response = await _authService.LoginUser(loginRequest);
        Response.StatusCode = response.StatusCode ?? StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        return new JsonResult(response);
    }
```

[image: postman_result]

Where have I got it wrong and how do I resolve it?

Thanks in advance

When I removed

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Username is required!")]
```

I got this errors:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'userName')
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
at Core.Services.v1.Concrete.AuthService.LoginUser(LoginRequestDto request) in C:\UsersCore\Services\v1\Concrete\AuthService.cs:line 48
at Web.Controllers.v1.AuthController.Login(LoginRequestDto loginRequest) in C:\Users\App\Controllers\v1\AuthController.cs:line 33
at lambda_method182(Closure , Object )

AuthService.cs:line 48:

> var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);

AuthController.cs:line 33:

> var response = await _authService.LoginUser(loginRequest);

Comment: Could you please try adding a [FromBody] attribute at the action parameter?

Comment: In `postman` how are you sending request using `raw` or `form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @Anduin - I still got the same result. I have updated the post with the controller change and postman response. What else do I do? Thanks

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - raw. See my updated code towards the end

Comment: Okay checking... could you please share `_userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName` and `_userManager.CheckPasswordAsync` details inplementations

Comment: As there are lot of dependency, but it seems that issue is throwing from `LoginUser` method

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - I have added the DbContext and IdentityModel I created to the post. As I said, The user logs in with UserName (and not email) and Password.   _userManager.FindByNameAsync is just to check if UserName exists

Comment: Yes I got your point `UserName (and not email) and Password` here email is not causing the error, Its may be bucause your `UserName` is not recognized while you are passing the param. did you had debug in which line it exactly breaking?

Comment: Here `user = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),`  how's your `user` domain model looks like?  Does this method `var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);` returning the same domain model?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Everything is in my code. user = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user) is just to map UserDto with ApplicationUser   while user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName)   is to check if the user with UserName really exists

Comment: Well, inside `response.Result = new` if you comment out `user = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),` this line does it return the token and validity time in response?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Still the same thing. But from my observation, I think it stops at LoginRequestDto in the Controller. It tries to check     public class LoginRequestDto
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Username is required!")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The password is required!")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }   and that's where it gets the validation message: Username is required. So It's not even getting to authservice

Comment: Thanks for the response, then please comment out `var response = await _authService.LoginUser(loginRequest);
        Response.StatusCode = response.StatusCode ?? StatusCodes.Status200OK;` and return like this 
        `return new JsonResult(loginRequest);` it should return with 200 so that we can understand where the problem is.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Still the same validation message. As I said earlier, I think it stops here:   Login(LoginRequestDto loginRequest)    .  It tries to check LoginRequestDto  and then generates that validation message

Comment: Could your try like this `[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequestDto loginRequest, [FromServices] IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions> apiBehaviorOptions)
        {
            if (loginRequest.UserName == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(loginRequest.UserName), "Invalid reuqest");

                return apiBehaviorOptions.Value.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory(ControllerContext);
            }

            return Ok(new { loginRequest.UserName, loginRequest.Password });
        }`

Comment: Just copy the the code snippet part and after if part replace `var response = await _authService.LoginUser(loginRequest);
        Response.StatusCode = response.StatusCode ?? StatusCodes.Status200OK;` let's see then

Comment: If still doesn't resolve then I need to have a look on your `ConfigureServices` sequence on  `Startup.cs` file

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Uh! I really appreciate your efforts. but still the same error.  What could be wrong with LoginRequestDto?

Comment: Depends on `asp.ent version` which version you are using?, could you please remove annotations `[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Username is required!")]` then try what happend? depnding on asp.net version  `annotations` yells sometime.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Kindly check the last part of my code I just updated for the error it displays when I removed [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Username is required!")].

Comment: That's mean when you are sending the request its getting empty request, does your controller getting value?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - I changed the validation for UserName in LoginRequestDto to         [Required]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }  and also commented     user = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),           It works.  But if I remove the comment on user = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),  then I got this error:  Mapping types:
Object -> UserDto
System.Object -> Core.DTOs.v1.Authentication.UserDto
   at lambda_method196(Closure , Object , UserDto , ResolutionContext )

Comment: I would suggest check type of your domain model and DTO, seems in line no 196 some conversion error encountered.